# L2 norm of the diagonal entries of a random rotation of a fixed matrix?

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, integration, haar-measure

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be the diagonal matrix with $d/2$ entries equal to $1$ and $d/2$ entries equal to $-1$. Let $F_U \triangleq \frac{1}{d}\|\operatorname{diag}(U^{\dagger}XU)\|^2_F$ denote the sum of squares of the diagonal entries of $U^{\dagger}XU$. If $U$'s columns consisted of independent random complex unit vectors, then we know that $\mathbb{E}[F_U] = \frac{1}{d+1}$, and $\Pr\left[\left|F_U - \frac{1}{d+1}\right| > t \right] \le e^{-\Omega(t/d^{3/2})}$.

Now suppose $U$ is Haar-random unitary, in which case we still have that $\mathbb{E}[F_U] = \frac{1}{d+1}$. My question is: **does $F_U$ concentrate comparably in this case?**

Weingarten calculus tells us that $$\mathbb{E}[F_U^n] = \sum_{\substack{\sigma,\tau\in \mathbb{S}_{2n}: \\ \tau \text{ has only even cycles}}} d^{\kappa(\tau)}\cdot \operatorname{Wg}(\sigma\tau^{-1},d)\cdot \Pr_{s\in[d]^n}[\sigma \text{ fixes the word } (s_1,s_1,s_2,s_2,\ldots,s_n,s_n)],$$ where $\kappa(\cdot)$ denotes number of cycles, but it is not clear to me how to get a good estimate for this quantity for large $n$. Alternatively, perhaps a stretch, but is there some HCIZ-esque way of computing the MGF of $F_U$?

Comment: The concentration you state in the independent column case is very weak. Are you sure about the normalization? Shouldn't it be $e^{-ct^2d^2}$, which would be consistent with the variance of $F_U$?  In any case, have you tried to apply Corollary 4.4.28 in Anderson-Guionnet-Zeitouni's book? I think this is what it gives.

Comment: Yes, I messed up the normalization. Because $U\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\|\text{diag}(U^{\dagger}XU)\|_F^{1/2}$ is $O(1/\sqrt{d})$-Lipschitz, Corollary 4.4.28 will indeed give $e^{-\Omega(t^2d^2)}$ tails. Thanks very much!